# Can't commit and push to github repository

Tags: linux, github, visual-studio-code

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWiZg.png)

Hi,

I'm trying to commit and push my work onto github. However, I can't.

Seems like it's saying some of the files i'm trying to push are too large.

But that's why I specified the .csv and .pt files in .gitignore.

I am not sure why .gitignore is not working as it should.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Bye.

Comment: Don't abuse tags. Why `python` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first commit and push your .gitignore file before it is considered by Git.

Comment: yes, checkout all your changes, commit a previous .gitignore, then use git add instead of git -a to commit useful files only

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
git rm -rf --cached
```

then

```
git add
```

this should remove all the files from ur commit cache and then add them back but using the ignore